# WCF service hosed in application can't be accessed from javascript?

Tags: javascript, wcf

I have an console application which starts a WCF service, and I want to access it in an html file using javascript.

Don't want to use web.config because it seems too complicated. and I want to host the service in an addon of an application later. (but if web.config meets my requirement, it is ok to use it too).

Following is the service code:

```
  class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080");
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAddress))
        {
           host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
           host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHelloWorldService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "bh");
           host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHelloWorldService), new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None), "wb");
           host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");
           host.Open();
           Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
           Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
           Console.ReadLine();
           host.Close();
        }
     }
  }

  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IHelloWorldService
  {
     [OperationContract]
     [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/SayHello?name={name}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
     string SayHello(string name);
  }

  public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
  {
     public string SayHello(string name)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("called SayHello");
        return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
     }
  }
```

And I want to access the service using javascript from a single html file, e.g. index.html like this:

```
jQuery.post("http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldService.svc/wb/SayHello", {name:"kii"}, function(ret){alert(ret);}});
```

Or like this:

```
jQuery.get("http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldService.svc/wb/SayHello?name=kii",  function(ret){alert(ret);}});
```

But they don't work.

"POST" method got "404 Not Found"
and
"GET" method got "405 Method Not Allowed"

Any suggestion?

thanks very much~~

Comment: Can you please show the web.config file? It is essential to see what your behavior and endpoint configuration looks like in order to give you a helpful answer.

Comment: jQuery.get("http://localhost:8080/SayHello?name=kii",  function(ret){alert(ret);}});

Comment: @PatchesTheClown, I don't have web.config file, because I'm going to embed the service in an application plugin and don't know if it still works if using web.config.

Comment: @yyou, no that does not work, still got "405 Method Not Allowed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the modified program for your reference.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080");
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
            typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAddress)) {

            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(
                new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(IHelloWorldService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "bh");

            var webEndPoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(IHelloWorldService), 
                new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None), "wb");
            webEndPoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(
                ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, 
                MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");
            host.Open();

            var n = 0;
            foreach (var endPoint in host.Description.Endpoints) {
                Console.WriteLine("endpoint " + n);
                Console.WriteLine(" address: " + endPoint.Address);
                Console.WriteLine(" absolute path: " + endPoint.ListenUri.AbsolutePath);
                Console.WriteLine(" absolute uri: " + endPoint.ListenUri.AbsoluteUri);
                n++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");

            Console.ReadLine();             
        }
    }
}
```

The only actual difference is to add WebHttpBehavior into the web endpoint.

running this program, and open brower to test address localhost:8080/wb/sayhello?name=abc 
if the brower returns "abc", that means the web end point is working. 
if calling this address by jQuery is still not working, then trouble-shooting on jQuery side.

Comment: fantastic!!!! thanks so much!!! I noticed I need to add corresponding code for this guy       <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>, but couldn't found the entry point because it is under behaviors>endpointBehaviors

Comment: I'm back again.. @yyou, I found we can get the response text using browser, but no response from ajax like the example I show above. any idea? thanks.

Comment: I think it is a cross domain problem, because in "http://localhost:xxx" webpage, I can get the right result. but in a single html file in disk, I can't

Comment: Finally, I've got it to work using JSONP method, ````jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8083/wb/sayhello?name=sdfsfd",
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); 
    }
});```` , and before that, I need to set CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled to true: ````new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None) { CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled = true }````